# How to detect expired session vs. no session

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, filter, listener

The requirement is this: When a user session is expired, call expired.htm page, but on the first connection to the web site, show login.htm.

I tried using a filter but it doesn't work, I'm not able to tell to filter how to understand if it's a new request or an old request expired. This is the code I used:

```
if (session.getAttribute("userProfile") == null) {

    logger.debug("Session: " + ( session.isNew() ? "true" : "false"));
    logger.debug(request.getSession().isNew()); 

    if ( request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() )  {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:expired.htm");
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:login.htm");
    }


}
```

I tried different solutions proposed here on Stack Overflow and on the general internet, but nothing has worked and every request goes to `expired.htm`.

Comment: I'd say that if the user sends an invalid session id the session can be considered to be expired, i.e. for getting an id the user would either have to have visited the site already or have copied a link with a session id.

Comment: I also checked isNew but it's always true, also when the session is expired (I activate a listener that shows me when the session expires)

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the session object? Before doing that, use

```
if (request.getSession(false)==null) {
  // no session present (expired or new visitor)
  [... do something ...]
} else {
  // active session present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the validation above before use any attribute in the session. Because if the session don't exists you can't get an attribute of it.
You need to put false inside parentesis.

```
if(request.getSession(false) == null) { //Session don't exists
...
}
```

Java explain:

public HttpSession getSession(boolean create)

Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.

If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null.

To make sure the session is properly maintained, you must call this method before the response is committed. If the container is using cookies to maintain session integrity and is asked to create a new session when the response is committed, an IllegalStateException is thrown.

Parameters:
create - true to create a new session for this request if necessary; false to return null if there's no current session

Returns:
the HttpSession associated with this request or null if create is false and the request has no valid session